# Pandas filter a column based on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

Given this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(\
{'name': {0: 'Peter', 1: 'Anna', 2: 'Anna', 3: 'Peter', 4: 'Simon'},
 'Status': {0: 'Finished',
  1: 'Registered',
  2: 'Cancelled',
  3: 'Finished',
  4: 'Registered'},
 'Modified': {0: '2019-03-11',
  1: '2019-03-19',
  2: '2019-05-22',
  3: '2019-10-31',
  4: '2019-04-05'}})
```

How can I compare and filter based on the Status? I want the Modified column to keep the date where the Status is either "Finished" or "Cancelled", and fill in blank where the condition is not met.

```
Wanted output:

name      Status        Modified
0  Peter  Finished      2019-03-11
1   Anna  Registered  
2   Anna  Cancelled     2019-05-22
3  Peter  Finished      2019-10-31
4  Simon  Registered
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `where` + `isin`

```
df.Modified.where(df.Status.isin(['Finished','Cancelled']),'',inplace=True)
df
Out[68]: 
    name      Status    Modified
0  Peter    Finished  2019-03-11
1   Anna  Registered            
2   Anna   Cancelled  2019-05-22
3  Peter    Finished  2019-10-31
4  Simon  Registered
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.